# Variable Scope in JQuery misbehaving

Tags: jquery, json, scope

I have the following js + jQuery code with some misbehaving var scopes...or at least a misbehaving coder :-p

```
var lookup_output="";  //believe this makes it a global scope

function lookupWord(word) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/jianti/' + word + '.json';
    lookup_output = "abc";

    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, word_data){
                    lookup_output += "<div> trad: " + word_data.fanti + "<br>";
                    lookup_output += "simp: " + word_data.jianti + "<br>" ;
                    lookup_output += "pinyin: " + word_data.pinyin + "<br>" ;
                    lookup_output += "def: " + word_data.def + "<br>" ;
                    lookup_output += "</div><br>";
                    alert(lookup_output);
            });     
    });

    lookup_output += "123";
    return lookup_output;
}
```

the problem is that the line

```
return lookup_output;
```

gives back

```
"abc123"
```

whereas the line

```
alert(lookup_output);
```

gives

```
"abc123<div> trad: 交流<br>simp: 交流<br>pinyin: jiāo liú<br>def: exchange/give-and-take/to exchange/to alternate/communication/alternating current (electricity)<br></div><br>"
```

i want the return line to give out the same as the output...any ideas how?   i thought that by attaching it to a global variable it would do it, but seems not.

Comment: race condition? the return lookup_output is reached before the getjson function is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a scoping problem, you have a problem with the asynchronous nature of the `$.getJSON` call. `$.getJSON` is an AJAX call and the "A" in "AJAX" stands for "asynchronous". When you call `$.getJSON`, it will return you'll continue on yo `lookup_output += "123"`, then later, the `$.getJSON` callback function will get called.

The usual approach is to add more callbacks:

```
function lookupWord(word, callback) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/jianti/' + word + '.json';

    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        var lookup_output = "abc";
        $.each(data, function(i, word_data){
            lookup_output += "<div> trad: " + word_data.fanti + "<br>";
            //...
        });
        lookup_output += "123";
        callback(lookup_output);    
    });
}
```

Then, you'd call it like this:

```
lookupWord("someword", function(lookup_output) {
    // Do whatever needs to be done with the result.
});
```

Comment: @AdamA: Hello again, I thought that avatar look familiar.